# Laravel - How to delete a job (Notification)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my application an user can schedule a message (like a reminder) and when is the time, a popup appear on the application. For this, i've created a Notification and i send this through Websocket.

Now, suppose the use has insert a wrong date (or simply, want to change the remind date), i need to access the JOB before this is executed.

I did tried many solution, but no works...

My Notification class is:

```
class RemindNote extends Notification implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Queueable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
}
```

**Tried handle method on RemindNote:**

```
public function handle($event) {
   $this->delete();
}
```

Having `php artisan queue:work` activated, when i schedule the notification, the handle method is never called.

**Tried** `Queue::before` **on** `AppServiceProvider`

This method is called but if i call `$event->job->delete()`, the notification is always fired - job deleted. But, if for example i call `$event->job->release()`, the job is re-scheduled

So, there is a way to access JOB payload and delete it BEFORE it is executed?

**EDIT**

```
\Queue::before(function(JobProcessing $event) {
    \Log::debug($event->job->isDeleted());
    $event->job->delete();
});
```

With this, when the job is processed i see this in laravel.log:

```
[2017-07-27 16:44:35] stage.DEBUG:   
[2017-07-27 16:44:36] stage.DEBUG:
```

And, the notification is always fired. It seem that delete() on before hook do not have effect.

**EDIT**
This is the payload logged on Queue::before (method $event->job->payload()):

```
[2017-07-27 15:00:13] stage.INFO: array (
  'job' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call',
  'data' => 
  array (
    'commandName' => 'Illuminate\\Notifications\\SendQueuedNotifications',
    'command' => 'O:48:"Illuminate\\Notifications\\SendQueuedNotifications":6:{s:14:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'notifiables";O:45:"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier":2:{s:5:"class";s:26:"App\\Repositories\\User\\User";s:2:"id";a:1:{i:0;i:29;}}s:15:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'notification";O:28:"App\\Notifications\\RemindNote":7:{s:4:"body";s:3:"ddf";s:4:"user";O:45:"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier":2:{s:5:"class";s:26:"App\\Repositories\\User\\User";s:2:"id";i:29;}s:2:"id";s:36:"e160802c-e9e5-4d2c-a1e1-d63cbdceb54c";s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";N;s:5:"delay";O:13:"Carbon\\Carbon":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2017-07-27 14:31:00.000000";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:11:"Europe/Rome";}s:6:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'job";N;}s:11:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'channels";a:1:{i:0;s:9:"broadcast";}s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";N;s:5:"delay";r:14;}',
  ),
)  
[2017-07-27 15:00:13] stage.INFO: array (
  'job' => 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastEvent',
  'data' => 
  array (
    'event' => 'O:60:"Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated":6:{s:10:"notifiable";O:45:"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier":2:{s:5:"class";s:26:"App\\Repositories\\User\\User";s:2:"id";i:29;}s:12:"notification";O:28:"App\\Notifications\\RemindNote":7:{s:4:"body";s:3:"ddf";s:4:"user";O:45:"Illuminate\\Contracts\\Database\\ModelIdentifier":2:{s:5:"class";s:26:"App\\Repositories\\User\\User";s:2:"id";i:29;}s:2:"id";s:36:"e160802c-e9e5-4d2c-a1e1-d63cbdceb54c";s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";N;s:5:"delay";O:13:"Carbon\\Carbon":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2017-07-27 14:31:00.000000";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:11:"Europe/Rome";}s:6:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . 'job";N;}s:4:"data";a:1:{s:4:"body";s:3:"ddf";}s:10:"connection";N;s:5:"queue";N;s:5:"delay";N;}',
  ),
)
```

Comment: You'd have to remove it from the queue. How you do *that* depends on which queue engine you're using.

Comment: I'm using a database queue

Comment: You can find the record in the database and delete it, then.

Comment: If in Queue:before i access to job id and then delete (\DB::delete('delete from jobs where id = ' . $id);) nothing happen, maybe the record will be deleted, but the notification is fired...

Comment: That doesn't surprise me - the job details have already been fetched and are about to run. You could probably throw an exception after deleting it - should stop the worker, and then the job is gone the next time it checks the DB.

Comment: So.. there is no way to cancel a job... if i get the JOBID, then i DELETE it from database (and commit), then i mark it as deleted (the delete() method) and throw an exception, the notification is not executes... but... for each of this, laravel log this as an exception.. but is just an hack to stop the job execution... mmm... i dont like a lot this solution..

Comment: There might be - my knowledge of the Queue internals isn't perfect. I'm just offering my thoughts on possible solutions based on what I *do* know.

Comment: Yes and till now is the only solution i have... i think in Laravel queue is not often used and maybe the purpose of queue is not about "schedule a job and later cancel it"....

Answer (score 0):

You can run a callback on the `Queue::before` event.

Mark the reminder as deleted in the database, then in your `Queue::before` callback, check if the job has been deleted, if it has, remove the job from the queue before it is processed.

See job events on the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#job-events

**[edit]**
Just seen your edit. The job should not be processed if you use `job->delete()` is it possible that this is a bug with delayed jobs?

Also, have you stopped and restarted the queue listener when you make changes to your class? I fell into this trap.

Comment: I tried to place $job->delete() inside Queue::before but the job is always executed. Now, i placed a log with isDeleted() and after that i call delete(), the log show an empty row. See my edit

Comment: @Mistre83 Have you tried dumping the entire event into the log to see what's there?

Comment: Yes, when the worker process the job, if i log the payload() i can see all the information.. one relative to CallQueueHandler and the other relative to BroadcastEvent... but no help.. i updated the thread.